# Mysql db restore

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with restoring a db.
I'm writing some tests for a php script. Tests add much data to different MYSQL db tables, especially when I debug them (tests), then I have to quickly restore the previous version of the db and run the tests again, but it's a long process to restore the dump. When the db size is 25 mb it takes almost 1 min, it's fine, I can wait 1 minute, it's not good but ok, but if the db is more than 2 gb it takes too long.

Maybe you know of any fast methods to restore a db or dump or log changes then revert them. My tests change only a few tables, but each time the changed tables are different and I can't know from test which tables were changed.

-- ADDED --
I need full a backup or a method to know what was changed because I don't know which tables were changed.

I make a full SQL dump and then simply restore it with mysqldump
--- ADDED -- 
My DB is using MYISAM

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, how you are taking backup but looks like you don't need a full backup. Rather, take a differential or incremental backup and restore the same. Which will be much faster than a full backup restore. See Mysql documentation on [Restoring an Incremental Backup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.12/en/restore.incremental.html) for more information

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking what is it now, may be this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Have a problem with restoring. I have run command "mysqlbinlog bin_log.000001 | mysql" before it I deleted all from db, but it restores nothing. Add the dates but it doesn't work mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2016-11-28 22:49:00" --stop-datetime="2016-11-28 22:55:00"  bin_log.000001 | mysql .